# KeyError: 'data' error in instagram script working with no issues on low numbers but not on numbers above 100-150

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, instagram, instagram-api

I have an Instagram script for generating the list of followers and unfollowers into separate excel files. It works on accounts having 50-60 or fewer followers and following but as soon as I use it on an account with 100+ followers/following it gives me the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "insta-unfollower.py", line
>   229, in 
>       main()   File "insta-unfollower.py", line 183, in main
>       followers_list = get_followers_list()   File "insta-unfollower.py", line 140, in get_followers_list
>       for edge in response['data']['user']['edge_followed_by']['edges']:   KeyError: 'data'

Here is the function

```
def get_followers_list():
    followers_list = []

    followers_post = {
        'query_id': 17851374694183129,
        'variables': {
            'id': session.cookies['ds_user_id'],
            'first': 60
        }
    }
    followers_post['variables'] = json.dumps(followers_post['variables'])
    response = session.get(query_route, params=followers_post)
    response = json.loads(response.text)

    for edge in response['data']['user']['edge_followed_by']['edges']:
        followers_list.append(edge['node'])

    while response['data']['user']['edge_followed_by']['page_info']['has_next_page']:
        time.sleep(random.randint(5, 15))

        followers_post = {
            'query_id': 17851374694183129,
            'variables': {
                'id': session.cookies['ds_user_id'],
                'first': 3,
                'after': response['data']['user']['edge_followed_by']['page_info']['end_cursor']
            }
        }
        followers_post['variables'] = json.dumps(followers_post['variables'])
        response = session.get(query_route, params=followers_post)
        response = json.loads(response.text)

        for edge in response['data']['user']['edge_followed_by']['edges']:
            followers_list.append(edge['node'])

    return followers_list
```

here is the main function call

```
def main():
    if not os.environ.get('USERNAME') or not os.environ.get('PASSWORD'):
        sys.exit('please provide USERNAME and PASSWORD environement variables. Abording...')

    is_logged = login()
    if is_logged == False:
        sys.exit('login failed, verify user/password combination')

    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))

    connected_user = get_user_profile(os.environ.get('USERNAME'))
    print('You\'re now logged as {}'.format(connected_user['username']))
    print('{} followers'.format(connected_user['edge_followed_by']['count']))
    print('{} following'.format(connected_user['edge_follow']['count']))

    time.sleep(random.randint(2, 6))

    print('building followers list...')
    followers_list = get_followers_list()
    print('found {} followers'.format(len(followers_list)))
    for i in followers_list:
        l1.append(i['username'])
        l2.append(i['full_name'])

        df = DataFrame({'User name': l1, 'Full Name': l2})
        df
        df.to_excel('followers.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
    print ("input success")



    is_logged_out = logout()
    if is_logged_out:
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Can you post sample of `response` ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I have made the changes now the indentation should be fine. :)

Comment: please check the line `df` and `df.to_excel(...)` I would guess they need unindentation - also the stray `df` has any purpose?

Comment: it seems `https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/` is no longer officially documented -so no idea - see [instagram 2018 graph-api-changes](https://elfsight.com/blog/2018/02/instagram-graph-api-changes/)

Comment: Instagram has changed its policies- agreed. but why is it working on accounts with a relatively low number of followers/following? If it was the case then it shouldn't have worked on those accounts too.- @PatrickArtner

Comment: count your blessings. maybe they left it open for small-time users but not big-timers. I just dug around some, I do not use instagram - but if something works for one set of params and not for second set: mostly data is to blame, in your case the API - such things make me curious

Comment: Your error essentially tells you that you get no response from the api - the `'data'` entry is missing, as to why: I blame the API changes and there is not much that _we here_ can help you with that if it is the crux of your problem - sorry

Answer (score 0):

The documentation suggests that this code could have worked in the past, but will no longer work due to the provider de-supporting that endpoint. Consider porting this code to their new Graph API.

Comment: Can you help me port this on graph Api?